# Django form on the model

Tags: django-models, django-forms

I have Guest model in my app:

```
class Guest(models.Model):
event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name='guests')
contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name='guests')
attending_status = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=ATTENDING_CHOICES, default='no_rsvp')
number_of_guests = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
comment = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default='')
updated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Event and Contact I fill up by myself in Admin when creating a guest. On the site all I want is a guest to fill up the form where he refreshes his attending status, points out number of guests and leaves a comment.

```
class RSVPForm(forms.Form):
attending = forms.ChoiceField(choices=VISIBLE_ATTENDING_CHOICES, initial='yes', widget=forms.RadioSelect)
number_of_guests = forms.IntegerField(initial=0)
comment = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=False, widget=forms.Textarea)
```

How can I save the changes to the Guest model instance? How can I access the guest's id when saving the changes to his profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for Django's `ModelForm`s. Instead of subclassing `forms.Form` in your RSVPForm class, you should subclass `forms.ModelForm`. Then you can use the features of the model form class to help you achieve what you want (hide some fields, etc). An example is below:

```
class RSVPForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Guest
        fields = ('attending_status', 'number_of_guests', 'comment')
```

This will do essentially what you want, but you will need to remember to provide an `instance` keyword argument to the form constructor in your view function. This argument is the instance of the `Guest` model you will be updating with the form.

```
form = RSVPForm(instance=guest_object)
```

Now calls to the `form.save()` method will automatically save the new data to this `Guest` object instance. You just need to make sure that you always pass the instance keyword argument, even when using `request.POST`:

```
form = RSVPForm(request.POST, instance=guest_object)
```

Comment: After trying some other things I also came to the conclusion to use ModelForm. Your clear explanation was very useful for me! thank you.